# Why don't we say blessings for solar eclipses

Tags: blessing

Why don't we say blessings for solar eclipses? After all, we gladly say blessings for other natural occurrences. For example, we say blessings when we see a tree, animal, lightning, earthquakes, the latter two which are more harmful and terrifying than an eclipse, which is only part of the natural order, that occurs as often as five times a year.

Since it is a natural phenomenon of natural forces, why do we refer to eclipses as omens instead of blessings?